# Библиотека для приветственного интерактивного объяснения дизайна сайта

Tags: javascript, библиотеки

На многих сайтах наблюдаю, тот же google или facebook, в момент первой регистрации предлагает пройти "инструктаж" по работе с их системой. Аналогично в играх при первом заходе.
Все работает по следующей схеме, затемняются ненужные элементы, а нужные подсвечиваются и рядом объяснение, что делает конкретный элемент. Таким образом пользователя ведут по всей системе, объясняя как с ней работать.
Я помню, что когда-то находил подобную библиотеку на JS, но сейчас, не могу найти. (Более того, не могу сформулировать поисковый запрос)
По этому обращаюсь к сообществу за помощью.

Кто ни будь знает, название этой библиотеки или способы реализации подобного функционала?

Answer (score 0):

http://bootstraptour.com/ - Как раз таки подобный функционал.
Формулировка такая: Интро Тур по сайту.

https://introjs.com/ - еще один отличный вариант